# Fasting using hunger control pills?

Tags: sawm, ramadan

There are some medicine to help dieting that would control the feeling of hunger. Is using those kinds of dieting pills allowed when fasting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Allah doesn't want us to fast for the sake of keeping stomach empty or does He? The essence of fast is in giving up your needs/desires for Allah and bearing the effort of trying to over come them.

Sahih Bukhari:

> Narrated Abu Huraira: Allah's Apostle said, "Whoever observes fasts
>   during the month of Ramadan out of **sincere** faith, and hoping to attain
>   Allah's rewards, then all his past sins will be forgiven."

Just like taking performance enhancement drugs in a game is cheating similarly taking such a drug for fasting would be cheating with Allah and therefore the 'sincerity' part will be gone.

And Allah (S.W.T) knows best.

Comment: This, strictly, doesn't answer whether the consumption is allowed or not. Please elaborate on that.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is.

According to [Jafari Fiqh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ja'fari_jurisprudence)

> eating hunger control pills during fasting time is not allowed but
>   eating them before morning Azan is not Haram and one can eat it.

This was Fiqh answer (Halal/Haram).

But morally and spiritually it is better to feel hungry to understand poor people more and to feel closeness to God and to remember God more.

---

**References:**

[Official website of Grand Ayatollah Makarem Shirazi](http://makarem.ir/websites/english/estefta/) (online answering by Chat)